# Disable resizing of ckeditor not working

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a ckeditor inside dialog box of jquery.I need to make the ckeditor non resizable.I have tried `config.resize_enabled = false;`,but its not working. I have also tried to set `max-width`,then also its not working.

```
<script src="include/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="include/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>

<textarea id="dialog_description" style="width: 440px; max-height: 200px; min-height: 170px;">
</textarea>
```

```js
$(function() {
    CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
        config.resize_enabled = false;
        config.resize_maxWidth = 600;
    };

    $("#dialog_loader").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: "auto",
        modal: true,
        minWidth: 800,
        autoOpen: false,
        position: 'center top',
        open: function() {
            $('#dialog_description').ckeditor();
        },
        close: function() {
            $('#dialog_description').ckeditorGet().destroy(); 
        },
        buttons: {
            //some stuff
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `resize_enabled = false` should work fine, assuming you're using CKEditor v3+. Have you checked your version?